# JIMP Image being cut short

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jimp

I am using Node.js, Express, NodeMailer, and JIMP to try to email an image after a POST. Sending an email with a completed image works when requests are spaced out but when I send multiple, sometimes old images are sent instead or partial images. I decided to cut out email for the moment and just do `res.sendFile(myImage)` to test that JIMP is finishing its work before the next line is called.
This results in partial images being displayed and I'm not sure why?

I also get the error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

The relevant code is below.

```js
var Jimp = require('jimp');


app.post('/invite/:email/:name', async (req,res) => {
  try {
    var email = atob(req.params.email);
    var name = atob(req.params.name);
    var data = req.body;
    const inviteImage = await makeImg(name, data);
    res.type('png')
    res.sendFile(__dirname+`/${inviteImage}`);
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }
});


async function makeImg(name, data) {
  try {
    let name2 = data["Name"];
    let style = data["Style"];
    let fanciness = data["Fanciness"];
    let dressMsg = dress(fanciness);
    let dateTime = data["Date"];
    let regex = /([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)T([0-9]+\:[0-9]+)/;
    let match = dateTime.match(regex);
    let ordinal = getOrdinal(match[3][1]);
    let month = getMonth(match[2]);
    let date = `${match[3]}${ordinal} ${month} ${match[1]}`;
    let time = `Time: ${match[4]}`;
    
    let smallFontName;
    let largeFontName;
    let image;
    let filename = "";
    if(fanciness <= 3){
      image = await Jimp.read('./imgs/casualTemplate.png');
      filename = "Casual";
      smallFontName = Jimp.FONT_SANS_64_WHITE;
      largeFontName = Jimp.FONT_SANS_128_WHITE;
    }else if(fanciness > 3){
      image = await Jimp.read('./imgs/fancyTemplate.png');
      filename = "Fancy";
      smallFontName = Jimp.FONT_SANS_64_BLACK;
      largeFontName = Jimp.FONT_SANS_128_BLACK;
    }

    let width = image.bitmap.width;

    let [smallFont, largeFont] = await Promise.all([Jimp.loadFont(smallFontName), Jimp.loadFont(largeFontName)]);
    
    // Print Greeting
    await image.print(smallFont, (width-650)/2, 162, {
      text: `${name} invites ${name2} To:`,
      alignmentX: Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER,
      alignmentY: Jimp.VERTICAL_ALIGN_TOP
    }, 650, 162);

    // Print Date Activity
    await image.print(largeFont, (width-810)/2, 340, {
      text: `${style}`,
      alignmentX: Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER,
      alignmentY: Jimp.VERTICAL_ALIGN_CENTER
    }, 810, 505);
    
    // Print Dress fanciness
    await image.print(smallFont, (width-810)/2, 970, {
      text: dressMsg,
      alignmentX: Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER,
      alignmentY: Jimp.VERTICAL_ALIGN_TOP
    }, 810, 66);

    // Print date of the date
    await image.print(smallFont, (width-810)/2, 1080, {
      text: `${date}`,
      alignmentX: Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER,
      alignmentY: Jimp.VERTICAL_ALIGN_TOP
    }, 810, 66);

    // Print time of the date
    await image.print(smallFont, (width-810)/2, 1187, {
      text: `${time}`,
      alignmentX: Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER,
      alignmentY: Jimp.VERTICAL_ALIGN_TOP
    }, 810, 66);

    await image.writeAsync(`./a${filename}Invite.png`);
    
    return `a${filename}Invite.png`;
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Only the top of the image has rendered and saved, the grey shows how much more was left undone:[image]

Comment: Looks like you're reusing the same filename instead of generating a unique one each time, so concurrent requests are mangling the file.

Comment: I thought Node.js uses like a queue and handles one POST request at a time

Comment: No, that's not at all how Node.js works. It can handle many (hundreds/thousands) of concurrent requests.